# ffmpeg fails to read m2ts files from libaacs

Tags: ffmpeg, blu-ray

I have a bluray disc that I am attempting to convert on Manjaro Linux using libbluray and libaacs.
`AACS handled` shows "yes".  Additionally, VLC plays the bluray with no problem. but when I attempt to rip the bluray using ffmpeg, it shows `Invalid data found when processing input`.
It shows the same message from both ffmpeg and ffprobe, and I have the same issue with 2 different blurays.

I have followed the instructions at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Blu-ray, and scoured google as well.  Not sure if this is a problem with libaacs/libbluray, or with ffmpeg.

ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg version n6.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.1 (GCC) 20230801
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libplacebo --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpl --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-vulkan
  libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102
  libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
  libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100
  libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100
  libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100
  libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
BDMV/STREAM/00000.m2ts: Invalid data found when processing input
```

libaacs version 0.11.1-2

libbluray version 1.3.4-1

bd_info output:

```
Using libbluray version 1.3.4
BluRay detected     : yes
First Play supported: yes
Top menu supported  : yes
HDMV titles         : 12
BD-J titles         : 0
UNSUPPORTED titles  : 0

BD-J detected       : no

AACS detected       : yes
libaacs detected    : yes
Disc ID             : 6AFF420869157CF15668ABF81812F5640D5FD4BC
AACS MKB version    : 3
AACS handled        : yes

BD+ detected        : no

Application info:
  initial mode preference : 2D
  3D content exists       : No
  video format            : ignored (0x0)
  frame rate              : ignored (0x0)
  initial dynamic range   : SDR (0x0)
  provider data           : '                   Provider Name'

No disc library metadata
```

Comment: https://github.com/justdan96/tsMuxer